# Uncertain how to solve this trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently attempting to discover how to find the general solutions to $$\sqrt 3\tan^2x=2\tan x+\sqrt 3$$

The given solutions are $x= \frac{\pi}{3}+ \pi k$ , $\frac{5\pi}{6} + \pi k$

To solve this equation I removed the square root from $\sqrt 3\tan^2x$ leaving me with $\tan x$.
Then I subtracted $2\tan x$ from $3\tan x$ leaving me with $\tan x=\sqrt 3$.

Should I then not solve $\tan x = \sqrt 3$ for the generalized solutions?

This would give $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $x=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ which would then be generalized to $\frac{\pi}{3} + \pi k$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3} + \pi k$, which doesn't agree with the given answers.

Comment: $\sqrt 3 \tan^2 x = (\sqrt 3) (\tan ^2 x) \ne 3 \sqrt{\tan^2 x}$. You need to solve a quadratic equation in $\tan x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Let }u=\tan x. $$

Divide through by $\sqrt{3}.$

$$ u^2 -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}u-1 = 0.$$

This is a quadratic equation, the solutions are:

$$u =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \mp \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

We thus have$$ \tan x = \sqrt{3} \quad \text{ or } \quad \tan x = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

So $$x \in \left\{\frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi, \frac{5\pi}{6} + k\pi\right\}.$$

Comment: Perfection! Thank you kindly for the breakdown, this explanation makes sense.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on player3236's comment: Let $u = \tan x$. Then your equation is $\sqrt{3} u^2 = 2u + \sqrt{3}$. Solve this quadratic equation, and then use $u = \tan x$ to solve for $x$.